# A question about the distance between points and closed convex subsets of Hilbert Space.

Tags: geometry

Let S be a non-empty, closed and convex subset of an infinite dimensional and separable Hilbert Space H. If p is any point of H, there exists a unique point f(p) of S whose distance from p-in the standard metric of H-is smaller than the distance of any other point of S from p. Let d(S,p) denote the distance between p and f(p). Are f(p) and d(S,p) continuous functions of p at all points p of H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to see that
$$d(S,p) + d(p,p') \ge d(S,p') \ge d(S,p) - d(p,p')$$
so $d(S,p)$ is continuous (this works for any nonempty set $S$ in any metric space).

As for $f(p)$:

If $v = f(p) - f(p')$, $\langle p - f(p), v\rangle \ge 0$ (otherwise  $t f(p) + (1-t) f(p')$ would be closer to $p$ than $f(p)$ for some $t \in (0,1)$).  Similarly, $\langle p' - f(p'), v\rangle \le 0$.  So $$\|p - p'\| \|v\| \ge \langle p - p', v\rangle  \ge \langle f(p) - f(p'), v \rangle = \|v\|^2$$  i.e. $\|f(p) - f(p')\| = \|v\| \le \|p - p'\|$.

Comment: Very nice answer! I think you need to take the real part of the inner products to cover complex Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thanks alot, Robert, for your response.